# Right-click on a menu item and popup a context menu

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I am using Java/Swing to add a JMenu with JMenuItem's.  I want to add some optional complex actions to each menu item, but without having to add more cluttering hierarchical menus.

Is it possible to capture a right-click on a JMenuItem and use this event to open a JPopupMenu context menu?  When I try to right-click on a JMenu item the event is consumed to perform the menu action.  Is it possible to intercept and override this with a mouselistener?

My intended behaviour is:

- left-click do menu action
- right-click show popup menu

Comment: Create a sub menu for the menu item. The popup will be displayed automatically but you can then add a MouseListener to menu item to handle the mouse click. Post an [mre] if you need more help and for all questions in the future.